# How to access google cloud datastore in my app

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-datastore

there is any way that I can access Google cloud datastore with rest API or something else.
I build angular 4 app as the front end I hosted on firebase hosting and I want to access cloud datastore with firebase functions or some rest API. 
There is any person in the entire world that can post - show me how I can do this if I can't use cloud datastore any alternative

Comment: Cloud Functions run in a Node.js environment. So you should be able to use https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore

Comment: Frank thnx you again . can i ask you if i can install cloud/datastore inside firebase hosting /functions

Comment: or i nead an app engine instanse to do that

Comment: Cloud Functions run in a node environment. The package I linked is meant to run in a node environment. So they should work together. Now I didn't try this myself and there's always a chance they won't work together. But your best bet is to simply try using it and posting back if you get an error. In that case your "can this work?" would have turned into a "why doesn't this work?" which is much more likely to get an answer.